# Is there any serious project going on using PROLOG?

Tags: prolog

```
   **Is there any serious project going on using**
```

[image: PROLOG]
<sub>(source: [atarimagazines.com](http://www.atarimagazines.com/startv2n5/prolog.jpg))</sub>

```
                         **?**
```

Comment: Apparently as serious as a well-dressed, though jpeg artifacted robot chewing on a neon tube.  (me thinks this is one of those "either you get it, or you dont" kind of things.. and obviously I dont)

Comment: May I reiterate? The *serious* question is: "Is there ...". Not: ".. must be .." or "..should be..".

Comment: English is not my mother tongue, but for some reason he title does not feel right - "Is there a serious project" or even better - "are there any serious projects" (just in case you are ready for a surprise).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SICStus and LPA Prolog cite selected customer applications that sound very serious, for example:

- **Clarissa**, a fully voice-operated procedure browser developed by the NASA Intelligent Systems Division.
- A dispensation order generation algorithm for **Pyrosequencing**'s sequence analysis instruments, using constraint programming with SICStus.
- **Logistics** applications by RedPrairie.

Source:

**https://sicstus.sics.se/customers.html**

Comment: Here are some other [SICStus based products](https://www.sics.se/projects/sicstus-prolog-leading-prolog-technology)

Comment: Some others are mentioned in chapter 6 of [SICStus Prolog - the first 25 years](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.5640)

Answer (score 3):

[SWI Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/) claims [10,000 downloads per month](http://www.swi-prolog.org/logs/dl-statistics.html), so somebody must be using it for something.

Comment: I had to learn it in college.. can't say I have touched it since.

Comment: It is certainly much used in education. For good reasons I think. Here a 'starter-kit': https://prof.ti.bfh.ch/hew1/informatik3/prolog/p-99/

Answer (score 3):

You might want to visit the [Commercial Users of Logic Programming Workshop](http://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~tom.schrijvers/CULP2010/) to find out.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Additionally http://groups.google.com/group/cu-lp

Answer (score 3):

I've been working on industrial/commercial applications of Prolog since the 1980's. These include: natural language applications (Lockheed), CASE (Knowledgeware), compilers (Quintus), call center applications (Quintus), Event Management (IBM DataHub, Tivoli), Text Mining (Price Waterhouse, Kaidara), and now Event Managment again (BMC Software).

If you have a chance to learn it, do so. There is nothing else like it. Unfotunately, jobs in it are as rare as hens teeth. If you want to work in a beautiful language that has some traction, consider Scala.

Answer (score 2):

Cisco owned the [ECLiPSe](http://eclipseclp.org/) platform for a long while (eventually released it as open source) and uses it for network management decision support applications.

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Prolog](http://www.visual-prolog.com/) selling his commercial licenses for €299
So there should be some money-making projects.
See also [Prolog Development Center](http://www.pdc.dk/About/about.asp)

Answer (score 1):

The [Cyc project](http://www.cyc.com/) uses a language which is extremely similar to Prolog, from what I've seen. According to them, the main reason they do not use Prolog is that it does not scale to the size of databases they deal with.

So while it's not a direct answer to your question, I think it might satisfy the "is Prolog actually used for series stuff" thought.

More information:

- [Wikipedia page for Cyc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyc)
- [A brief explanation of their language, CycL, and why they don't use Prolog](http://www.cyc.com/cyc/technology/whatiscyc_dir/howdoescycreason)
- [Some more information about their inference mechanics](http://www.cyc.com/cycdoc/ref/inferencing.html)